# AngularJS: input field with date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I guess, this is some beginner question, but I don't know, what to search for.

I have a timesheet which should look like this:

```
    From  |  To   | Pause | Hours 
   [08:00] [17:30] [01:00]  08:30
```

The values in brackets (08:00, 17:30, 01:00) are input fields, the hours should be a calculated value.

So this is my form:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in timesheetCurrentMonth">
    From: <input type="text" ng-model="t.from"/> <!-- e.g. 08:00 -->
    To:   <input type="text" ng-model="t.to"/>   <!-- e.g. 17:30 -->
    Pause:<input type="text" ng-model="t.pause"/><!-- e.g. 01:00 -->

    Working hours:<span>{{t.to-t.from-t.pause|hhmm}}</span> <!-- e.g. 08:30   --> 
</div>
```

So how can I enter date values into the textfields like '08:30' and calculate the total working hours?

I was thinking about calculating with minute values (08:00 = 480) in the model, because I will persist these data as minute values in the database and it makes the calculation simple (to-from-pause). Does that make sense? BTW, I do have a filter, that converts minute values into the HH:mm format.

Thanks,
Bernhard

PS: Here's a function that converts minutes (like 480) to an HH:MM string (08:00).

```
var convertToHourString = function(min, alwaysShowMinutes) {
     var hours = Math.floor(min / 60); 
     var minutes = min % 60;
     if (minutes === 0 && !alwaysShowMinutes)
         return hours;
     return hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found it out by myself.

That was the question.
"So how can I calculate the total working hours?"

```
<span>{{calcWorkingHours(t.to, t.from, t.pause)|hhmm}}</span>
```

Scope: from=08:00, to=17:30, pause=01:00

So the variables to, from and pause will be converted into minute values, the working hours will be calculated (again as minute value) and outputted using a filter ('hhmm'), which converts sth. like 510 (minutes) into '08:30' hours.

Answer (score 3):

[momentJs](http://momentjs.com/) provides all the date/time operations and convertions you need.

Comment: This provides no insight into how to solve the OPs problem and, holy mother, do I hope one does not include an entire date library to do simply arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. rgthree is right here, this is not about converting times, as I already have the time operations (posted in the PS). I'm just looking for the Angular way to do my operations, i.e. I update the 'from' value, and the 'working hours' are calculated right away.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the math inside of your controller as a calculated property. You will need to create a new Date() with the strings that are being passed in before you can do the math.

Here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/khpfvo1u/

```
var start = new Date('2015-05-20 08:30:00');
var end = new Date('2015-05-20 15:30:00');

var result = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
alert(result);
```

Like Michael said, momentJS will give you far richer functionality for anything to do with dates. If you have anything beyond very simple math it's probably worth introducing the dependency.